# Can we have situations where thermodynamic extensivity is violated?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In thermodynamics, the internal energy $U$, the number of particles $N$, the entropy $S$, etc. are [extensive properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermodynamic_properties). Can there be situations where the extensivity is violated?

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Comment: Systems where the particles have long range interactions, e.g. in gravitationally bound systems.

Comment: @countIblis Why is that? By long-range interaction do you mean long range attraction?

Answer (score 3):

Just take a gas of electrons (without a neutralizing back ground, as in a plasma), and put them in a box with volume V. The Coulomb energy (per volume) diverges as the volume goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

If you just put your systems next to each other, each within its own box (perhaps coupled to the same bath) then of course $S$, $U$ and $N$ will be exactly extensive. If you bring the systems in contact, however, things are different.

Just analyse the microcanonics of a lattice gas and you will see it breaks the extensitivity of $S$ (this will be done explicitly later).

$U$ is never exactly extensive if the systems are actually brought into contact because there are interactions between the systems which shift the internal energy.

The case of $N$ is a bit different, at least if we are not in a relativistic scenario, since $N$ is a conserved quantity, so $N$ will be exactly extensive in the microcanonical and canonical ensemble. This need not be the case in the grandcanonical ensemble (since there the particle number depends on the energetics of the system and are only an average depending on the chemical potential of the bath).

But, for large, realistic systems, the extensive term is the term of leading order and since usual thermodynamic systems are large (in the sense that $N \gtrsim 10^{23}$) the correction terms are incredibly small (and can safely be ignored without sacrificing accuracy).

---

The lattice gas is a simplistic model where $N$ particles are distributed to $M$ sites. Any site can hold at most one particle and the particles at neighbouring sites do not interact.

The entropy in the microcanonical ensemble is known to be the logarithm of the degeneracy of the state at the considered energy. The degeneracy $g$ of the model is simply the number of arrangements of $N$ particles to $M$ sites, that is:
$$g = \binom{M}{N}.$$
The entropy is
$$ S = \ln(g) = \ln(M!) - \ln(N!) - \ln\big((M-N)!\big). $$
For a large system we can develop these expressions using the first few terms of the Stirling formula:
\begin{align*}
 S &= M \ln(M) - M + \frac 1 2 \ln(2\pi M) - N \ln(N) + N - \frac 1 2 \ln(2\pi N) - (M-N) \ln(M-N) + (M-N) - \frac 1 2 \ln\big(2\pi (M-N)\big) + O(1/N)\\
   &= M \ln\left(\frac{M}{M-N}\right) - N \ln\left(\frac{N}{M-N}\right) + \frac 1 2 \log\left(\frac{M}{N}\right) + \frac 1 2 \ln\big(2\pi(M-N)\big) \\
   &= N \left( \frac{M}{N} \ln\left(\frac{\frac{M}{N}}{\frac{M}{N} - 1}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{M}{N} - 1\right) \right) + \frac 1 2 \log\left(\frac{M}{N}\right) + \frac 1 2 \ln\left(2\pi N \left(\frac M N -1\right)\right) + O(1/N).
\end{align*}
If we put two of such systems $1$ and $2$ with identical densities $\nu = \frac N M$ in contact, this is equivalent to considering the system with $M = M_1 + M_2$ (that is the sum of the volumes) and $N = N_1 + N_2 = (M_1+M_2)\nu$ (the sum of the particles in the systems). As you can see in the leading term only the only change is that the factor $N$ changes to $N_1 + N_2$ (as the density stays the same). But the $O(\ln(N))$ term violates exact extensivity of the entropy. However, for $N \gtrsim 10^{23}$ we have $\ln(N)/N \lesssim 5 \cdot 10^{-22}$, so the relative error due to the corrections is negligible. 
The next-leading term is the intensive term $\frac 1 2 \log\left(\frac M N\right)$, and the corrections to the order $O(1/N)$ which can be neglected on similar grounds in the thermodynamic limit.